is there any way to update User Email in firebase using android studio (java)
When I run the app and try to change the email the Toast is "useremail  not updated":
THIS IS THE ERROR
email not updated
com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthException: This operation is not allowed. This may be because the given sign-in provider is disabled for this Firebase project. Enable it in the Firebase console, under the sign-in method tab of the Auth section. [ Please verify the new email before changing email. ]
at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzach.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@23.0.0:39)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzadg.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@23.0.0:21)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzacz.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@23.0.0:35)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzadb.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@23.0.0:75)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzacf.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@23.0.0:46)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzaad.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@23.0.0:3)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzyu.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@23.0.0:2)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzadp.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@23.0.0:15)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzadp.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@23.0.0:64)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzacw.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@23.0.0:105)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzyl.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@23.0.0:43)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzyr.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@23.0.0:8)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzadp.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@23.0.0:20)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzadp.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@23.0.0:64)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzacw.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@23.0.0:54)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzyl.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@23.0.0:35)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzaad.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@23.0.0:9)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzyl.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@23.0.0:90)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzyl.zzb(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@23.0.0:58)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzaci.zzb(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@23.0.0:17)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzabx.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@23.0.0:15)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzadi.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@23.0.0:2)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
at com.google.firebase.concurrent.CustomThreadFactory.lambda$newThread$0$com-google-firebase-concurrent-CustomThreadFactory(CustomThreadFactory.java:47)
at com.google.firebase.concurrent.CustomThreadFactory$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(D8$$SyntheticClass:0)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
// Get auth credentials from the user for re-authentication
AuthCredential credential = EmailAuthProvider
        .getCredential(user.getEmail(), "123456789"); // Current Login Credentials \\
// Prompt the user to re-provide their sign-in credentials
user.reauthenticate(credential)
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                Toast.makeText(ProfilePage.this, "User re-authenticated.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //Now change your email address \\
                //----------------Code for Changing Email Address----------\\
                FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                user.updateEmail("user@example.com")
                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    Toast.makeText(ProfilePage.this, "User email address updated.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }else{
                                    Toast.makeText(ProfilePage.this, "useremail  not updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                //----------------------------------------------------------\\
            }
        });


When a Task fails in Firebase, there is an error object associated with that task.  What does the error message say?  As of now, you've done nothing with that object to find out what exactly went wrong.

So as Doug says, do something like: log.e("Auth", "email not updated", task.getException()); to find out the root cause of the problem.

Please edit your question and add the information Doug and Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.

@AlexMamo i edited the ask with the error in logcat

You are getting the following error:

This operation is not allowed. This may be because the given sign-in provider is disabled for this Firebase project.

Because you didn't enable Firebase sign-in with email and password inside the Firebase Console. To solve this, please enable it under the sign-in method tab of the Auth section in the Firebase Console. So please click "Add new provider", then select " Email/Password" and enable it.

Still having the same problem

The only thing that works with me by replacing (update email) by( verify email before update)
